# ng-bind-html working, but throwing error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using `ng-bind-html` to render sanitized comment HTML. This is my html:

```
<span class="commentBody" ng-bind-html="comment.Text"></span>
```

It works - the HTML is rendered and displays correctly. But I get the following error in the Javascript console:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'push'
   at $$addBindingInfo (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:6869:9)
   at ngBindHtmlLink (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:20460:9)
   at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:8219:9)
   at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:7729:11)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:7078:13)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:7081:13)
   at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:6957:30)
   at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:7096:9)
   at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:7756:11)
   at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost:2239/Scripts/angular.js:24553:15) <span class="commentBody ng-binding" ng-bind-html="comment.Text">
```

This is the code that causes the problem in `angular.js`:

```
  var bindings = $element.data('$binding') || [];

  if (isArray(binding)) {
    bindings = bindings.concat(binding);
  } else {
    bindings.push(binding);
  }
```

The `bindings` variable ends up being the string `comment.Text`, which is why it doesn't support the method `push`, because it's not an array.

What should I change to fix this?

Comment: what is in $element.data('$binding')?

Comment: I should have been clearer - that part is not my code, it's part of angularjs. It seems to be part of what automatically happens when I use ng-bind-html. I will try stepping into $element.data to find out I suppose.

Comment: On Internet Explorer?

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: It happens on IE and Chrome. I can't actually reproduce it in a jsfiddle, so it must be something I'm doing wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Phil - no. I had a think about it, and I realised I didn't really need angular to sanitize my html for me, since I was doing it myself. I ended up creating a very simple directive of my own to bind (one-way) to html:

    `myApp.directive("presanitizedHtml", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    scope.$watch(attrs.presanitizedHtml, function (html) {
                        elem.html(html);
                    });
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: @user1002973 That directive did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right .push will only work with an array. Using this you have to initialize your variable

```
var bindings = new Array();
```

you might also try to consider using .pushStack =>  http://api.jquery.com/pushstack/

Comment: I should have been clearer - that part is not my code, it's part of angularjs. It seems to be part of what automatically happens when I use ng-bind-html

Comment: ok have you tried to add 'ngSanitize' to you module dependencies ---> var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

Comment: Yes, ngSanitize is in my dependencies. And it's working! It's redendering the html (and getting rid of potentially malicious content). The only problem I have is this error message in the JS console. The webpage functions completely fine.